# XSLT element count

Tags: xslt, count

I want to count no of elements under a node , In below XML I has 2 report entries , In first entry I has 4 elements and in 2nd entry I has only 3 address is missing.

I want to count the total elements under each report_entry
count is 4 for first report entry and count is 3 for 2nd report entry

Can some body suggest is it possible ? any sample code ?

example xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <report_data>
     <report_entry>
    <id>12345</id>
    <fname>Venkata</fname>
    <lname>Penumatsa</lname>
    <address>Hyderabad</address>
       </report_entry>
        <report_entry>
    <id>123453</id>
    <fname>stephen</fname>
    <lname>florida</lname>
      </report_entry>
    </report_data>
```

-- Venkata

Comment: Yes, it's possible: use `count(*)` from the context of  `report_entry`. Post your existing code and the expected result if you need more help.

Comment: Hi Michael, I used the below code . It gives me the count of total report entries  ,i.e. 2 but not how many sub elements are there inside of report entry

Comment: <xsl:template match="/*">        
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(/report_data/report_entry)"/>       
                        </xsl:template>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question instead - and add the expected result too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="report_entry">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(*)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

if you "want to count the total elements under each report_entry".

Comment: If, I have "report_entry" include sub-elemnt, how to calculate include sub-elements of "report_entry"?